# Why I can't get tabs list to debug page from FirefoxOS browser on desktop?

Tags: debugging, firefox, firefox-os, gaia

I have ZTE Open with Firefox OS.

I have macosx laptop. (And also parallels with windows vista, 7, 8 etc. if it may help…)

I enable remote debuging and console in phone settings and remote debuging in Firefox Nightly on desktop.

Download adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917 from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
and run:

```
./adb devices
    List of devices attached 
    roamer2 device
```

So device is connected
Then I run

```
./adb forward tcp:6000 localfilesystem:/data/local/debugger-socket
```

Because this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging
Then I open Firefox and

```
Tools -> Web Developer -> Connect…
```

[image: "screen"]

And nothing… Just timeout. Then I try

```
./adb forward tcp:6000 tcp:6000
```

Get this on my ZTE Open:

[image: "screen"]

Click "Ok" and get this on my desktop:

[image: "screen"]

No tabs!
What I am doing wrong?!
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Remote debugging requires Firefox OS 1.2 or greater, which I do not think has been released for the ZTE Open.

More information regarding remote debugging with App Manager (simulator):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Using_the_App_Manager#Firefox_1.2.2B_required

And here's some info on the ZTE Open:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/ZTE_OPEN

Answer (score 0):

The instructions from @christi3k work for remote debugging an app within Firefox OS on my ZTE Open C.

When I want to debug a classic webpage, it's not working at all within Firefox OS context.
It will only work in an Android context according to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1009518 but maybe I miss something.